# Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax INSERT with BIND PARAM

Tags: mysql

I cant solve the issue with this code, syntax sql issue maybe.

Have tryed to change in many ways the INSERT sql tag. I dont know if i need to use single quotes or not on this. Tryed both already.

Can anyone help please?

```
if(isset($_POST['order'])) 
   {


    //values to be inserted in database table
    $order = $_POST['order']; #order
    global $restaurant;
    $request_time = date('H:i'); #request_time
    $status = "requested"; #status
    $date = date("m.d.y"); #date
    $assigned_to = "";

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','foodcour_user','1020304050@','foodcour_db');
        if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
            die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
        }

    $query = "INSERT INTO products (product_code, product_name, price) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
    $query = "INSERT INTO 'deliverys' ('restaurant', 'order', 'request_time', 'status', 'date', 'assigned_to') VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?')";
    #$statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    if( ! $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query) ) {
  echo 'Error: ' . $mysqli->error;
  return false; // throw exception, die(), exit, whatever...
} else {
  //bind parameters for markers, where (s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob)
    $statement->bind_param('ssssss', $restaurant, $order, $request_time, $status, $date, $assigned_to);

if($statement->execute()){
    print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$statement->insert_id .'<br />'; 
}else{
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
}
$statement->close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following query is wrong

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO 'deliverys' 
('restaurant', 'order', 'request_time', 'status', 'date', 'assigned_to')
 VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?')";
```

get rid off quotes on the column names and table names

order is a reserved word need back ticks ``

get rid off single quotes on ? in bind params

```
$query = "INSERT INTO deliverys 
(restaurant, `order`, request_time, status, date, assigned_to) 
VALUES 
(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```